# Working on SQL Server CE 3.5 file over lan for multiple users

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq, sql-server-ce-3.5

I'm working on a project with C# (vs2010 environment) this project require a SQL Server CE 3.5 database for several functions. Working on a local `.sdf` for one user shows no problem but when I run my project with `.sdf` over network it gives me `sql.ce` errors.

Is this problem happens because using it over lan or because using it with multiple users?

And how can I solve that issue.

Comment: SQL Server CE is **NOT** designed to be used over the LAN, nor is it designed to be used by multiple users. If you need this functionality -> use SQL Server **Express** instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992713/sql-server-ce-in-a-multi-user-scenario-is-this-really-really-stupid

Comment: is there any way to use third-part software beside sql server ?

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple users you have to try SQL Server Express Version (free) or Mysql, 
you can see [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212217/how-do-i-share-a-sql-server-ce-database-file-sdf-for-multiple-processes) post it will be helpful